# Questions about copy IIS config files to another server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, iis-7, migrate

I have several asp.net web services is running in IIS. Now I want to move to another server in all exactly same IIS setting and using same web services. I know about copying a IIS config files(ApplicationHost & administration) to new server remotely but do I also need to copy all asp.net files to new server as well? If yes then must the asp.net files be in the same file path directory as the current one(D:\Website) for IIS in new server to be able to recognize it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would need to copy the ASP.NET files as well.

It is not necessary to put them in the same file path directory. Whatever directory you put them in, ensure your IIS Website Settings point to that directory and you have setup the same set of permissions etc. on it.

e.g. You could have had a website on c:\site on one web server. you could move the website files onto another web server and put them on d:\newsite\ and change the Website Directory Path in IIS Manager to point to D:\newsite\ directory.

Comment: Thank for response. I thought IIS will already included same permission/auth within config files?